# Should I use Europass format or create custom resume template when applying for internships?

Tags: software-industry, resume, europass

I'm a European CS student, looking to apply to a few companies for a summer internship. I am building my resume, but I'm wondering whether I should go with the standard Europass format, or a custom format - and by custom, I don't mean a different structure, but maybe a lighter, more padded table structure, different formatting, maybe a different font, etc.

Would this have a particular (positive/negative) impact? Would it help my resume stand out (I personally (optimistically) think that this *shouldn't* matter, that only the content and actual experience should matter, that it's not some fancy font and center-aligned subsection titles that should make the difference, but I feel that I should ask anyway), or would it hurt my chances? (one example of custom template would be the one described in [this article](http://texblog.org/2012/04/25/writing-a-cv-in-latex/))

I've seen a lot of debates regarding this topic and no definite answer. So, should I stick to the already existing resume templates, or should I roll my own.

For what it's worth, I'm using XeLaTeX to typeset it.

Right now, I've just went with the Europass format (edited in OpenOffice Writer based on the official templates), and sent it both to the US and European companies. I don't think that the Europass format would influence my result that much. After all, it's still a problem of whether a company based in the US or Canada is willing to also give me a work permit there (a.k.a. extra hassle).

As an extra tip, I've checked out [Google's Resume writing tips, as seen on their students page](https://www.google.com/intl/en/jobs/students/joining/). It's nothing out of the ordinary, but it's a good idea to clearly state the main accomplishments and the technologies used in every position you had as a programmer.

Comment: If you like TeX look into this package for creating CV: [timeline-cv](https://github.com/will-hart/latex-timelineCV). It is available in CTAN.

Comment: I would use MS Word rather than XeLaTeX it is going to be HR depts (and/or their software) reading your CV in the first instance.

Comment: @Neuro: XeLaTeX (as any other *TeX) would create .pdf, who need Word when .pdf is much better for this?

Comment: Sometimes they ask for the resume/CV in a specific format or even multiple formats. Almost all places in the US are expecting it to be as a text file so that it can be ingested by their automated systems.

Comment: +m0nhawk why pdf is a suboptimal format to work in for general use.

And the aim hers is to get your CV in front of the HR Dept and 99.99% of hr dept will prefer word.
And is the Latex pdf generator any good will it slow machine to a crawl look good on everyone

Comment: @Neuro: Yes, I'll be creating PDFs. I wasn't planning on sending .tex files :P. Yes, the generated files are really good quality.

Comment: ill add my full comment again as the SO system is broken 

+m0nhawk why pdf is a suboptimal format to work in for general use.

And the aim here is to get your CV in front of the HR Dept and 99.99% of hr dept will prefer word in fact some might just ignore non word versions. And is the Latex pdf generator any good will it slow machine to a crawl when I open it  look good on everyones machine (are all the fonts there) - there is a reason there are professional preflight tools for PDF's for this very reason - you checked it on the 3 main versions of Windows Os 10 using the FF and IE PDF plugins?

Comment: @Neuro - We prefer to get PDFs for CVs via our online recruitment system;  I've encountered more issues with Word documents than PDFs when displaying them, and I've foudn they open more easily on some mobile devices.  Word can be very risky - esepcially if people have left on "track changes"....

Comment: @AndreiBârsan To ask a clarifying question so that the comments and (hopefully) answers address the real question you're asking....when  you encounter advertisements for these positions, do they specify or not specify a format (either in style, such as Europass, or document type, such as Word/PDF/other)?

Comment: Thanks for the information so far! @jcmeloni On their website, they simply say "Submit your resume in PDF or Microsoft Word formats. Text formats are also acceptable." without mentioning anything about a particular format, such as Europass.

Comment: @AndreiBârsan what country are you applying for?

Comment: @crh225: The companies are in Romania and the UK. However, I'm thinking of also applying for an internship in the US. Would that would mean I'd need a different resume format?

Comment: @AndreiBârsan If applying in the US I would have something similar to [link]http://www.technical-resumes.com/cm/wp-content/uploads/2010/01/computer-programmer1.jpg If applying in another country, I would find out what is acceptable in Romania and UK. I would say the US version of a resume is different than the UK version. I had never heard of Europass format until this post. To me, the Europass format says "Hey I am foreign." Not that it is a bad thing.

Comment: @crh225 Thanks for the feedback. I'll just maintain two versions of the resume, sticking with the Europass one for applications within the EU, and using the US-style one when needed.

Comment: I've seen very smart people advocate that web professionals should host their resume online and build it using concepts that illustrate their ability (such as with Twitter Bootstrap, jQuery, using Modernizr...etc).

Comment: @JeromyFrench ah, I see; however, I would be applying for a more general, software engineer position; although I do have considerable front-end development experience, I don't know how well this would fit

Comment: Hi Andrei, if you have an answer to this question, consider posting a summary of what led you to the answer as an actual answer to this question so it helps future visitors. Try to include what criteria you used to come to that answer. Good luck! :)

Comment: @jmort253: Well, I'm still thinking about this. I have a formatted Europass version already done. I'll post the answer after I'm done with the application process!

Comment: @AndreiBârsan - Awesome. Another thing you can do if you don't yet have a good answer is [edit] your question with the details you've learned, which will help guide others to a point where they may have some substantial answers for you. Hope this helps! :)

Comment: I've got some good feedback by using [StackOverflow careers](http://careers.stackoverflow.com) for my CV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After roughly 4 months, here's a basic rundown of what happened:

- I ended up using the plain old OpenOffice Europass template for my resume, since I kept hitting various issues typesetting the Tex version. Next year I'll probably just re-do it using a format such as [timeline-cv](https://github.com/will-hart/latex-timelineCV) as suggested by m0nhawk. I don't really see the point of having the Europass logo all over your resume anyway.
- I did get interview offers from both European and American companies, so the Europass format wasn't an issue (and I wasn't really expecting it to be, anyway)
- another neat thing I noticed when I went to the interview for the american company (and they had printed their own copies of my resume) was that since my resume was optimized for **A4** and they had printed it on a **Letter** format, a huge chunk had shifted from the front page leaving a really ugly blank spot. That's something to keep in mind in the future.
- Microsoft's job site was (IIRC) the only one which actually attempted to scan my PDF data and then allowed me to edit it. It did a horrible job, but I could fix it with not too much effort. I don't even think it was the Europass format's fault.

Answer (score 3):

From my experience up to now, mainly in UK:

Many companies will want to parse your CV using an automated tool. Almost all tools are written to use Microsoft word format, this is the reason I have a .doc version of my CV and not a latex one.

Europass format is too verbose for most cases in UK (and maybe other places) so you might consider to check where you apply first. If many organizations would want a Eurpoass format one, you might prefer to have two versions.