# Can using auto generated resumes from job application reduce my chance of getting accepted?

Tags: resume, job-change

Considering my previous question [here](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/120260/how-to-increase-chance-of-you-getting-hired-if-you-are-not-a-native-to-that-coun) and one of the answer, one thing I thought I might be doing wrong is most of the times when applying online for a  job, I tend to use auto generated resumes that those websites generated based on my information entered for my profile. So when I apply for job over Stackoverflow jobs I use the default resume that it generates while applying from my profile. Or using LinkedIn profile with my application instead of a resume in PDF or word.

I wanted to know that will this lower chance of my application getting through? Is it fine to use this resumes or should I go through old manually made document? Usually I check and update profile around every 2 months.

Comment: This is going to depend entirely on what the auto-generated resume actually looks like. The fact that it was auto-generated won't matter if it looks good (and maybe if it's not obvious that it was auto-generated).

Comment: Not sure if this is on-topic or not. Just like we don't do resume review, we can hardly review resume generators on other websites. At the same time "*Should I use a resume generated by LinkedIn or one I made myself?*" seems like it'd be a useful question.

Comment: "*or should I go through old manually made document*" To be clear, you mean to update said old document right?

Comment: @Lilienthal I'm inclined to say this question just comes down to "what should a resume look like", which is probably too broad or opinion-based. We shouldn't really evaluate individual resume generators because the usefulness of that is entirely dependent on those things sticking around and not fundamentally changing.

Comment: @Dukeling Aye, I follow the point, but the general question might have value. In a way it's similar to [this question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/7349/should-i-use-europass-format-or-create-custom-resume-template-when-applying-for) on the Europass template. Though perhaps I should an answer of my own there.

Answer (score 2):

From what I've heard: **Yes, using auto-generated job resumes lowers your chances in an application process.**

Recruiters and personnel managers read hundreds of applications and resumes. If most of them are auto-generated, they basically look the same. Names and dates change, but it's still an endless stack of similar looking resumes. 
If yours doesn't have a special feature that sets it apart from the rest, it will just get lost in the shuffle.

I think it's a good idea to take example in an auto-generated resume but edit it a little bit to give it a personal touch. Make this one resume fit this job description more than all the others. Tell the company why they want to hire *you* instead of anyone else. Highlight your experiences that are most usefull in this specific job you're applying to. That makes your resume more memorable than all the rest of the auto-generated documents. It also shows more effort than clicking a button in an app.

Drasticly changing the layout of your resume, having spelling or grammar errors in it or making it otherwise look unproffessional is going to lower your chances.

Comment: If you're standing out because of the format of your resume, chances are that's something that makes your resume harder to read.

Comment: Frankly,  I'd love applicant resumes to follow a standard format/structure to make it easier to compare and assess candidates. The problem with auto-generated resumes isn't the format, but the non-targeted information - your resume should highlight how well you match the requirements of the job you are applying - if you use the exact same resume for every job you apply for, you're not doing it right.

Answer (score -1):

It differs for each individual if it's auto-generated from a third party, but if it's generated from their website you should use it.

It makes it easy for them to skim, various interested people may even only look at a section of the form which contains all the relevant details they need to see. Most are not interested in the format but the content. They may even have semi-automated processes which filter based on their template.

When I am part of an interview with a generated resume, as the tech expert I have a section to look at, the rest is irrelevant to me while we're narrowing down candidates. The concerned people are dealing with the other sections.

Answer (score -2):

Show some effort and especially personality man.
It's fine to take pointers from auto generated or example documents but always adjust them in tone and presentation to your own liking and the industry / company you're applying at.

You need to do the bulk of the work only once anyways.
The rest is just updating and tweaking.

Links to social media are not really the best option in my opinion.
They can be an addition / extension but you should always have a document they don't need to fish around for on the internet and which they can print out easily.

It needs to be concise, on point and convey all the important details at a glance.
Third party web pages have too much clutter.
Also, not everyone is as crazy about (certain) social media as social media tries to convince us to be...

...so to answer, yes it can harm your application.